# Calculating Slope in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm new to Tableau so I'm still learning.

So I have a basic graph. From the parameter, the user can choose to display the data in either a line graph or a slope graph. They can also filter on date range and location. It's basically a graph showing visits by location. The slope graph is just a straight line from the first point to the last point, depending on the date range the user chose.

If the slope graph is chosen, I need to display the numerical, calculated value of the slope somewhere on the graph, in addition to the line. The equation would be (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) but how do I calculate the slope in Tableau, when the date range and location can vary?

Comment: Can you please upload a screenshot of your view/dashboard (complete) so that i can understand it better? Moreover as no sample data is given, please try to translate your problem to superstore data!

Comment: If your x axis is date field won't the slope be relative and not absolute as desired?  I mean if x anf y axis represent different units how will you calculate the slope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, you have not given any sample data, I am trying to give a solution/walkthrough in Superstore (sample) data provided with tableau.

Let's take an example that you want to build an area chart for sales over a chosen period (filter 1) and for a chosen sub-category (filter-2).

**Step-1** Construct your desired view and add both filters to context (by right clicking them) . This will override the condition that calculations we are going to use in next step(s) will be calculated taken into account the filtered data only.

**step-2** Calculate five calculated fields as --
`X1` as

```
{min([Order Date])}
```

`X2` as

```
{max([Order Date])}
```

`Y1` as

```
{Sum(
IF [Order Date] = [X1] then [Sales] END
)}
```

`Y2` as

```
{Sum(
IF [Order Date] = [X2] then [Sales] END
)}
```

`Slope` as

```
([Y2]-[Y1])/DATEDIFF('day', [X1], [X2])
```

**Step-3** add all the five fields to details and create annotation as per taste.  In the example I have created a mark annotation as

```
During the period from <DAY(X1)> to <DAY(X2)>, the rate of increase (+)/decrease (-) in sales for sub-Category <Sub-Category> was  $<SUM(slope)>  per day.
```

This gives me a view like this.  **Needless to say I have calculated the slope in $/day; you can tweak it as per taste while inputting `datepart` in slope.**

[image: output]

Comment: Beautiful, it's working! That's what I needed! Thank you so much! I just have one more question. In my visual when I have multiple locations selected, I have separate line/slope graphs appear for each location for easy comparisons. How do I calculate the slope for each one? If I have just one location selected, then it calculates the slope perfectly but if I have multiple locations selected, then it ends up using the combined y2 and y1 for all the selected locations to calculate the slope. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I am glad that it helped.  Please upvote if you can though it is not mandatory.  Regarding your second question you can very well do that but then you'll have to change the calculation according to that level of detail (LOD). Try it.

Comment: In all of the four base calculations, just add `Fixed [location] :`

Comment: Moreover, if there will be many lines, so it will be helpful if you calculate one more field to segregate increase with decrease.

Comment: Yup the FIXED resolved it. You're my hero. Here's an upvote.